# ActionBar app icon as home

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I want the app icon in the top left to return up when pressed, I'm using

```
setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And the arrow by the icon appears, but pressing it doesn't actually do anything, why? Here's my oncreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    android.app.ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setTitle("Aritmetik");
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Aritmetik.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

(from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home)